# Solving a linear functional equation

Tags: reference-request, functional-equations, greens-function

Working with Green functions, I have found to solve the following equation
$$
   -\omega^2G(\omega)-m^2G(\omega)+\kappa\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_nG(\omega-n\omega_0)=1
$$
where $m$, $\kappa$ and $\omega_0$ are arbitrary constants, $b_n$ are coefficients of a Fourier series and so
$$
    \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty|b_n|^2<\infty.
$$
Is there any approach I can attempt to solve it? Is there anything in literature to approach this kind of problems?

Comment: I think pertubation theory is the way to go

Comment: $\kappa$ can be large.